# Projective representation of diffeomorphism group of $S^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory

We know that the projective representation of a group $G$ is classified by $H_{grp}^2(G,R/Z) = H^3(BG,Z)$, where $H^*_{grp}$ is the group-cohomology class. 
Then do we have a classification of the projective representations of diffeomorphism group of $S^2$ (or more generally, of $S^n$).

Comment: Do you mean infinite dimensional representations? Then you have to be much more specific what the target group is.

Comment: Note that every homomorphism from the full diffeomorphism group to a finite dimensional connected Lie group has image of order at most 2. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to comment on the sentence:

> "We know that the projective representations of a group G are classified by $H^2_{grp}(G,\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)=H^3(BG,\mathbb Z)$, where $H_{grp}$ is group-cohomology."

That is only true for a certain class of groups: those are the groups for which 
$H^3_{grp}(G,\mathbb R)=H^2_{grp}(G,\mathbb R)=0$.
This includes all compact Lie groups (in particular finite groups), but also loop groups of compact Lie groups.

The vanishing of $H^3_{grp}(G,\mathbb R)$ is a somewhat obscure condition, but the vanishing of $H^2_{grp}(G,\mathbb R)$ is very concrete: no central extensions by $\mathbb R$. Here are some examples of groups with non-vanising $H^2_{grp}(G,\mathbb R)$: $G=\mathbb R^2$; $G=\mathit{Diff}(S^1)$; and many more.

---

Concerning the question of $\mathit{Diff}(S^2)$, I don't think that it has any interesting representations -- at least I've never heard that being mentionned anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! Then how about the the Lie algebra for $Diff(S^2)$. Does the  Lie algebra has a centre extension?

Comment: I don't really know. I would guess not. What I do know is that that's called Gelfand-Fuschs cohomology. So the Gelfand-Fuschs cohomology of $S^2$ is the Lie algebra cohomology of the Lie algebra of vector fields on $S^2$.